# Set array field's length based on const integer field

Tags: c++, arrays, static-memory-allocation

Suppose I have a class...

```
class Foo
{
public:
  Foo(int size);

private:
  const int size;
  int data[];
};
```

Supposing that the size field is set immediately at instantiation, how can I set the length of `data` based on that size input?

I would ordinarily use a `std::vector` here, but I am writing a library for Arduino, so that won't fly, and I'm trying to avoid external dependencies if I can.

Comment: Does that require me to `delete` it later?

Comment: Deleting it is good hygiene, but not required. Is there some reason you don't want to?

Comment: Yes it does, but you can use a template-parameter for the size, this would allow you to use a fixed-size array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are out of luck here, as C++ must know the size of the array at compile time (in other words, the `size` must be a constant expression). Your options are to either use dynamic allocation

```
int* data;
```

then allocate with `new int[size];` in the constructor initialization list, or, better, use [`std::unique_ptr<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) (C++11 or later), which is a light wrapper around a raw pointer and deletes its allocated memory at scope exit, so you won't have to manually `delete[]`

```
class Foo
{
private:
    std::unique_ptr<int[]> data; // no need to manually delete
public:
    Foo(int size): data{new int[size]} {}
};
```

A third option is to make `Foo` a non-type template class (assuming you know the size at compile time, which is what it seems to be happening, at least judging from your question)

```
template<std::size_t size>
class Foo
{
    int data[size];
public:
    Foo() 
    {
        // constructor here
    }
};
```